# ExpatError: junk after document element

Tags: python, html-parsing, minidom

I really don't know, what the Problem is? I get the following error:

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\xml\dom\expatbuilder.py", line 223, in parseString
parser.Parse(string, True)
ExpatError: junk after document element: line 5, column 0
```

I DONT SEE NO JUNK! Any help? I'm getting crazy......

```
text = """<questionaire>
<question>
    <questiontext>Question1</questiontext>
    <answer>Your Answer: 99</answer>
</question>
<question>
    <questiontext>Question2</questiontext>
    <answer>Your Answer: 64</answer>
</question>
<question>
    <questiontext>Question3</questiontext>
    <answer>Your Answer: 46</answer>
</question>
<question>
    <questiontext>Bitte geben</questiontext>
    <answer>Your Answer: 544</answer>
    <answer>Your Answer: 943</answer>
</question>
</questionaire>"""

cleandata = text.split('<questionaire>')
cleandatastring= "".join(cleandata)
stripped = cleandatastring.strip()
planhtml = stripped.split('</questionaire>')[0]
clean= planhtml.strip()


from xml.dom import minidom

doc = minidom.parseString(clean)
for question in doc.getElementsByTagName('question'):
    for answer in question.getElementsByTagName('answer'):
        if answer.childNodes[0].nodeValue.strip() == 'Your Answer: 99':
            question.parentNode.removeChild(question)

print doc.toxml()
```

Thanx!

Comment: Don't remove the `questionaire` tag!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your original `text` string is well-formed XML.  Then you do a bunch of stuff to it that breaks it.  Parse your original `text`, and you will be fine.

XML is required to have exactly one top-level element.  By the time you parse it, it has a number of top-level `<question>` tags.  The XML parser is parsing the first one as a root element, and then is surprised to find another top-level element.

Comment: thanks... Can you recommend a good introduction into parsing html and xml?

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was caused by the changes made in `libxml2-2.9.11` that made `tostring()` (`lxml`) return more content (what follows the element) than it should. E.g.

```py
from lxml import etree

xml = '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<a>
  <b>
  </b>
</a>
'''
t = etree.fromstring(xml.encode()).getroottree()
print(etree.tostring(
  t.xpath('/a/b')[0],
  encoding=t.docinfo.encoding,
).decode())
```

Expected output:

```
<b>
  </b>
```

Actual output:

```
<b>
  </b>
</a>
```

Should you pass the result to `xml.dom.minidom.parseString()`, it will complain.

More on it [here](https://gist.github.com/x-yuri/8725b2176c8bc2b92a46f9da28d530b7).

To avoid this you either need `libxml2 <= 2.9.10`, or Alpine Linux >= 3.14.